# How do you separate two distinct tables stuck together?

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

Currently, the tables appear so:

[image]

I tried to drag Table 2 downwards to separate it from Table 1; but instead Table 2 then jumped upward and covered Table 1:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: I am using Word 2010, but the properties should be the same, they may just look different.*

In your table properties, check text wrapping and click <kbd>Positioning...</kbd>.

[image]

In the next window, uncheck `Allow overlap`.

[image]

Click <kbd>OK</kbd> twice to accept your changes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Insert a row at the bottom of Table 1.
2. Click on that row, right-click and choose the option to split a table.

Table 1 and 2 should now be two different tables.

Comment: The OP states the tables are already separate.

Comment: @CharlieRB I did; so this answer appears not to pertain?

Answer (score 0):

Select the whole of the second table, and Cut. Add a blank line at the bottom of the first table. Paste back the second table.